# What is this structure and how do I use it?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am still pretty new to angular and am trying to write unit tests for someone else's code. (They couldn't be bothered and now they've gone to better things.)

What is this structure?

```
export interface SomeState {
    services: { [lineItemNumber: string]: SomeService };
 }
```

Here is the line of code that's accessing it.

```
 const serviceTypeId = someState.services[id].serviceType.id;
```

It is being loaded from an API. I can't seem to figure out what to google to try to discover what kind of structure this is. I need to replicate the structure in my unit test and I can't figure it out.

Comment: And what's wrong with this question that got it downvoted? The fact that there were three wrong answers tends to prove that it's a difficult subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging and asking of help, I figured out that this structure makes use of computed property names, as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

So these computed property names are properties that are created at run time. To initialize them, here's what you do:

```
services: {[serviceId]: service}
```

Comment: services: { [lineItemNumber: string]: SomeService }; =>  describe the type and you are talk about set the lineItemNumber dynamic and this completely different thing

Comment: @malbarmawi The whole point was to set the value of something defined as above.

Answer (score 1):

If an object wants to implement the `SomeState` interface it simply needs to have a key named `services`, whose value is itself an object, whose keys are strings and whose values are of type `SomeService`

---

```
const someService: SomeService = .... // value of type SomeService

const valid: SomeState = {
  services: {
    a: someService
  }
}

const invalid: SomeState = {
  services: {
    b: 123 // Error -> the value of 'b' must be of type SomeService
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that is a dictionary. the structure is something like this:

```
{
'1': someService1,
'2': someservice2
}
```

someState.services['1'] returns someService1

Comment: It is not a dictionary.